# Create first Instant of year 2022

Tags: java, java-time, java.time.instant, date-manipulation

I have an `int` representing the year 2022, and I want to create an `Instant` object representing the first instant of the year, meaning: `2022-01-01 00:00:00`.

```
int year = 2022;

Instant instant = ...
```

How can we do that in java 8?

Comment: Unrelated, but Java 8 is quite old already. Consider upgrading, if possible. Latest version is 19.

Comment: @Zabuzard - The latest LTS version (17) would be a better choice than 19 ... unless the OP is happy to upgrade Java versions every 6 months on average.

Comment: Thank you guys, that was very helpful. If it was up to me I would upgrade to more recent of Java, but the client's app is running on java 8 so I need to work with that version.

Comment: In which time zone? New Year doesn’t happen at the same instant in all time zones.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick:

```java
int year = 2022;

Instant instant = Year.of(year) // 2022
  .atDay(1)                     // 2022-01-01
  .atStartOfDay()               // 2022-01-01 00:00:00
  .toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);   // applied to timeline
```

There are more ways, but they essentially all go kinda that route. Have a look at the Javadoc and explore more: [java.time package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should do the trick:

```
int year = 2022;
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("UTC");
Instant instant = ZonedDateTime.of(year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, zoneId)
            .toInstant();
```

Creates `ZonedDateTime` at 00:00:00 on the january 1 in the target year, at required time zone and converts to instant.